How to find missing PIDs with multiple matching criteria in Excel?
Question:
I have a dataset in Excel that contains information about PIDs, Customer_numbers, AccountSeqNums, and Transaction Dates. I am trying to find the missing PIDs based on specific matching criteria, but the formulas I have tried so far have not produced the desired results.
Here is an example of the dataset:
 PID | Customer_number  |   AccountSeqNum | Transaction Date

 P13245  Q12343  845321  4/1/2024
 P13246  Q12344  845321  3/27/2024
 P13247  Q12345  845321  3/19/2024
 P13247  Q12346  845321  3/18/2024
 P13247  Q12347  845321  3/1/2024
 P13248  Q12825  845322  3/1/2024
 P13249  Q12826  845323  2/28/2024
 P13250  Q12827  845324  2/28/2024
         Q12825  845325  2/28/2024
         Q12343  845321 
         Q12343  845321  1/30/2024
         Q12827  845324  1/28/2024

I want to find the missing PIDs where the Customer_number matches a specific value and the AccountSeqNum matches another specific value. Additionally, I need to exclude any rows where the PID is already filled.
I have tried using formulas like INDEX, MATCH, and COUNTIFS, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired results.
Excel Formulas tried:
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A2,A:A,0), MATCH(A2,B:B,1))
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$13,D2,$C$2:$C$13,E2,$A$2:$A$13,"")>0,"Missing","")
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$13, SMALL(IF(($A$2:$A$13="")(ISNUMBER(--$B$2:$B$13))(C2=$C$2:$C$13), ROW($A$2:$A$13)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW(A1))), "")
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10, MATCH(0, IF($A$2:$A$10<>"", COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10, $A$2:$A$10, $B$2:$B$10, $B$2:$B$10, $C$2:$C$10, $C$2:$C$10), ""), 0)), "")
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(REPT("z", 255), $A:$A)), MATCH(1, ($B$2:$B$12=Agent_number)(C2=$C$2:$C$12)(D2=$D$2:$D$12), 0)), "")
Could someone please help me with the correct Excel formula or approach to find the missing PIDs based on these criteria? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Also, Columns D, Transaction Date will have several missing dates.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Aside from that: please edit to include your efforts, expected results, actual results, etc (a [mcve])

Excel Formulas tried have been posted.

Ok.. so… what are they supposed to do, and what issues are there? You posted all of the formulas with no context. They are also unformatted text (and don’t forget to provide properly formatted sample data,  not an image )

So, my first trial formula has been the closest to the answer where I needed to continue down list with missing PIDs.  Other formulas only brought in blanks.
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A2,A:A,0), MATCH(A2,B:B,1))

If you have Office 365, you could use FILTER() with multiple criteria. See https://exceljet.net/formulas/filter-with-complex-multiple-criteria

@bugdrown, would you be able to share an example for my needed excel formula solution?

@Sweetcorn try =FILTER($A$2:$D$13,($A$2:$A$13<>"")*($B$2:$B$13="custnum criteria")*($C$2:$C$13="seq criteria")). As noted in the link, multiplication of compaison operations is equivalent to AND statements.

@bugdrown MS Excel says. The function is not valid.

@Sweetcorn What specific error is showing. If it's a #CALC! error then there are no matching rows for the given criteria. Did you change the criteria in the formula in your workbook? What criteria did you use?Please post your data table using Markdown.

I think you get the calc error because you are looking for Pid with a value if you change @bugdrown answer to  =FILTER($A$2:$D$13,($A$2:$A$13="")($B$2:$B$13="custnum criteria")($C$2:$C$13="seq criteria")) you find the rows  without any PID
